# Nav bar is hanging over header and not sure why?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website for practice and I'm having an issue where my nav bar is hanging over the header. I've tried adjusting the margin and that isn't working. I've tried changing the display and position, which end up just breaking the layout. My main goal is to have the navigation cleanly nestled in the bottom right of the header, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is the code I've typed:

Place the code into code snippets.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul,
li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li a {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

header {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px black solid;
}

.nav {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 175px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<header>


  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Menu</a></li>
      <li><a>Contact</a></li>
      <li><a>News</a></li>
      <li><a>About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Consider providing a codepen or jsfiddle so that it's easier to observe and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to replace your `.nav` class with:

```
.nav {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I assume this is more or less what you were trying to achieve with your margins.

An absolutely positioned element will be placed relative to the nearest positioned parent element (i.e. one with `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed` or `sticky` position). By default that is the highest level block, but since your header has `position: fixed` it is placed relative to that. The `bottom` and `right` values indicate the amount of offset from that block's respective edges.

Comment: yes. This worked like a charm. I am going to assume I was over-thinking the problem. I figured that the nav should be the child element of the header, but when I would try out different position and display, it would appear outside of the header which I thought was odd. I'm still trying to wrap my head around positioning with CSS, and especially position and display. I think I understand block/inline/inline-block well enough. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: No problem - with a bit of practice this will all become second nature :)

Answer (score 0):

The height of the header is 200px, but you left margin-top: 175px for the nav. For the nav to start where the header is ending, you need at least 200px as margin-top.

Comment: I actually want it nestled into the header, not below it. I tried it like you said and it placed it under the header. Good suggestion, just not what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please run the code snippet to check if this is the desired change. I have changed the position from `relative` to `absolute` and added `bottom: 0` and `right: 0` for class `.nav`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul,
li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li a {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

header {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px black solid;
}

.nav {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 175px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<header>


  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Menu</a></li>
      <li><a>Contact</a></li>
      <li><a>News</a></li>
      <li><a>About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Glad that I am able to help.

Answer (score 0):

There might be other ways, but using `flex` layout will solve your problem. 1st add `display:flex` in your header.

Then `.nav` with the following:

```
{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    align-self: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

See the final result:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul,
li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li a {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

header {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px black solid;
  display: flex;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-self: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<header>


  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Menu</a></li>
      <li><a>Contact</a></li>
      <li><a>News</a></li>
      <li><a>About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</header>
```

More details on how flex works, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox